# Passing data from a Child Component to the Parents Pop in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a button component which calls an API, and I want to push the returned response up to the parent, where it will become the 'translatedText' prop, however, I believe I'm using the $emit incorrectly, due to the error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$emit'). How do I best capture the response data and pass it to my parent prop, and is using $emit the best use in this instance?

TranslationButton.vue

```
    <template>
  <b-button type="is-primary" @click="loadTranslations()">Übersetzen</b-button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TranslationButton",

  props: {
   translatedText: ''
  },

  methods: {
     loadTranslations() { 
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/ccenter/cc_apis')
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.text();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          this.$emit('translatedText', this.data);
          console.log(data)
        })
      },
  },
};
</script>
```

Parent Component Props:

```
 props: {
    data: Array,
    translatedText: '',
    showAttachments: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    }

  },
```

How Child Component is called in Parent Component:

```
  <translation-button  @translatedText="loadTranslations()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practise when passing data from child to parent is emitting events.

```
this.$root.$emit('translatedText', this.data);
```

than

```
this.$root.$on('translatedText', () => { // do stuff })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Could you show me how you would apply that to my example? I've attempted to implement and am receiving undefined errors on the Emit Event.

Comment: Use $emit in mounted hook of child than use $on in mounted hook of parent component.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass data from child to parent, you need to use $emit like the below code

child:

```
    <template>
      <b-button type="is-primary" @click="loadTranslations">Übersetzen</b-button>
    </template>
    
<script>
export default {
  name: "TranslationButton",

  props: {
    TranslatedText: ''
  },

  methods: {
     loadTranslations() {
      const self= this; // change added
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/ccenter/cc_apis')
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.text();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          self.$emit('changeTitle', data) // change added
      })
  }
}
     
</script>
```

parent:

```
<template>
 <translation-button @changeTitle="ChangeT" />
</template>
......
methods:{
 ChangeT(title)
  {
   console.log(title)
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but title is returning undefined

Comment: Try checking if the payload contains any value before being emitted?

Comment: Also I have added some change to avoid `this` issue

Comment: @Amaarockz The payload is undefined before being emitted, I thought the payload was 'data'? Which is not undefined.

Comment: Removed the `.finally` block . Check edited answer

Comment: @Amaarrocks, thanks for the answer, but still TranslatedText prop is still undefined, which is main aim of this question, and console.log(title) just returns the word 'payload'

Comment: Sorry I forgot to remove the term `payload`. Also check if the data is printing on console before getting emitted

Comment: @Amaarockz the data prints on the console! But for some reason the $emit even isn't updating the TranslatedText props with a value of that data, the TranslatedRext prop remains undefined.

Comment: Is this on vue2 or vue3?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the usage of `this`. It does no longer point to your component inside the promise then() method.
You should create a new variable and initialize it with the value of `this` and use that variable to emit the event.

E.g.

```
loadTranslations() {
  const _this = this;
  fetch().then(response => _this.$emit(response));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

by emits you pass value to parent component,
@translatedText="loadTranslations()" - its event listner, fireing on your child comp emit

do @translatedText="loadTranslations" instead of @translatedText="loadTranslations()"

and add this loadTranslations as a method to parent comp

BTW

if you dont use arrow funcs, and you use this.data it's pointing to object passed to .then, it will be undefined i guess...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure I follow, how is it that you would structure the loadTranslations() method?